# Js анимация по высоте в обе стороны

Tags: javascript, анимация

Товарищи, есть html элемент высота которого 300px, и который после определенного момента появляется на странице. Задача заключается в том, чтобы его отрисовка по высоте была направлена в обе стороны, то есть вверх на 150px и вниз на 150px. Js изучаю, поэтому Jquery не юзаю. Вообщем, подскажите идею по реализации. Спасибо. Разумеется, размеры изменяются во времени

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну примерно так можно сделать.

PS: может в демо не совсем влазит.

```js
window.onload = ()=> {
  document.querySelector('.inner').classList.add('anim');
}
```

```css
.outher {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    display: flex;
    background: #ccc;
    position: relative;
}
.inner {
  width: 500px;
  height: 0px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  transition: 2s;
}
.inner.anim {
 height: 300px;
 top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outher">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```